# why it shows me only one collection from CloudFirestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux

im building a calendar using react, redux, firebase and react big calendar. On the main page i have 2 calendars that are the same but connected to a different collection in firebase each one. if i use them separately it let me post, delete, update and see the events but when i put together the 2 calendars i can only interact with only one collection.

Screenshot:

[image: calendar1]

[image: calendar2]

i think that the problem is in the state, because when i refresh the page, in the redux extension first appears the events of the first calendar and then the events of the second calendar. if this is the problem how can i solve it? i thought something like merging the events of the calendars into the state, but I don't know if this will make the same events appear in the 2 calendars again

i hope someone can help me

thanks a lot!

github: https://github.com/guidomora/peluqueria-new-calendar/tree/main/src

deploy: https://peluqueria-new-calendar.vercel.app/

redux extension:

[image: redux1]

[image: redux2]

calendarSlice.js:

```
initialState: {
    events: [],
    activeEvent: null,
    isLoadingEvents: true,
  },

  reducers: {
    onSetActiveEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.activeEvent = payload;
    },
    onAddEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events.push(payload);
      state.activeEvent = null;
    },
    onUpdateEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events = state.events.map((event) => {
        if (event.id === payload.id) {
          return payload;
        }
        return event;
      });
    },
    setEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events = payload;
    },
```

code to bring the events from firebase usig a custom hook: i use `${nombre}` to change the name of the collection in each component is just a string

useCalendarStore:

```
  const startLoadingEvents = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, `${nombre}`));
    const events = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      events.push({
        id: doc.id,
        start: doc.data().start.toDate(),
        end: doc.data().end.toDate(),
        title: doc.data().title,
        notes: doc.data().notes,
      });
    });
    dispatch(setEvent(events));
  };
```

Comment: The `startLoadingEvents` code you shared look fine at first glance. Are you sure that is enough to reproduce the problem with? You might want to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we need that **minimal-but-complete** code to be in the question, and not in a linked repo.

Comment: i added a little bit of more of code and explaining it, thanks for the advise!

Comment: I agree that we need to see a more complete [mcve]. What is the `"calendar/setEvent"` action creator and associated reducer function? Please [edit] and provide more complete code.

Comment: Added! Please let me know if anything else is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that the `calendarSlice` holds only the `events` state for a single calendar. Each time the `setEvent` action is dispatched it just replaces `state.calendar.events`. Whatever previously existed is simply overwritten.

From what it sounds like from your description though is that you need multiple `events` array, one for each calendar collection you are querying. You can update the `calendarSlice` to hold multiple calendar event arrays. I'm guessing that this collection id `nombre` is sufficient to differentiate/identify a unique calendar's events in state.

Example suggested refactor:

```js
const startLoadingEvents = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, `${nombre}`));
  const events = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    events.push({
      id: doc.id,
      start: doc.data().start.toDate(),
      end: doc.data().end.toDate(),
      title: doc.data().title,
      notes: doc.data().notes,
    });
  });
  dispatch(setEvent({ calendarId: nombre, events }));
};
```

```js
export const calendarSlice = createSlice({
  name: "calendar",
  initialState: {
    events: {}, // <-- { [nombre]: event[] }
    activeEvent: null,
    isLoadingEvents: true,
  },
  reducers: {
    onSetActiveEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.activeEvent = payload;
    },
    onAddEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (!state.events[payload.calendarId]) {
        state.events[payload.calendarId] = [];
      }
      state.events[payload.calendarId].push(payload.event);
      state.activeEvent = null;
    },
    onUpdateEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events[payload.calendarId] = state.events[payload.calendarId].map(
        (event) => event.id === payload.event.id) ? payload : event
      );
    },
    onDeleteEvent: (state) => {
      if (state.activeEvent?.calendarId) {
        state.events[state.activeEvent.calendarId] = state.events[state.activeEvent.calendarId]
          .filter((event) => event._id !== state.activeEvent._id);
        state.activeEvent = null;
      }
    },
    setEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events[payload.calendarId] = payload.events;
    },
    onLoadEvents: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isLoadingEvents = false;

      (payload.events || []).forEach((event) => {
        const exists = state.events[payload.calendarId]?.some(
          (dbEvent) => dbEvent.id === event.id
        );
        if (!exists) {
          state.events[payload.calendarId].push(event);
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

When selecting the state you'll need to update to consume `state.calendar.events` as an object instead of an array.

```js
const calendars = useSelector(state => state.calendar.events); // { [nombre]: event[] }

...

calendars[<name of collection>].map(event => { .... })
```

Obviously none of this is tested since I don't have access to your firebase backend nor did I standup any running codesandbox, but it should be a good general start for handling more than one calendar collection's data in the UI.

Comment: the only part i couldnt understand was `calendars["name"].map(event => { .... })`  where do i have to use it. im a little confused. But now in the redux extension i can see  **events: tobias: [{the events}], karina: [{the events}]**

Comment: @guido It's the name of the collections, e.g. `calendars["tobias"]` (*`state.calendar.events["tobias"]`*) or `calendars["karina"]` (*`state.calendar.events["karina"]`*). It's used in the UI.

Comment: @guido Sorry, I've updated the answer to hopefully make this part more clear.... `calendars["name"]` was complete valid javascript syntax and would compile if you simply copy/pasted, and would OFC fail as undefined unless you happened to actually have a collection named `"name"` ***and*** fetched it. This seems highly unlikely.

Comment: thanks so much! but now i cant get the activeEvent and upload, update or delete events. Just asked a new question, i would be grateful if you could continue to help me. i'm a bit confused about this.

Comment: @guido Ah, yeah, I didn't overtly call it out in the refactor, but several of the actions will now need to pass a `calendarId` property in the action creators. Examples: `dispatch(onAddEvent({ calendarId, event }))`, `dispatch(onSetActiveEvent({ calendarId, event }))`, etc, hopefully you get the idea from here.